# How to ignore object property on .GET but allow it on .POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following object in my c# web api project:

```
public class InfoUtente
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public string cellulare { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool termini { get; set; }
    public string fidelity { get; set; }

    public InfoUtente() { }
    public InfoUtente(string nome, string cognome, string cellulare, string email, string fidelity)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.cellulare = cellulare;
        this.email = email;
        this.fidelity = fidelity;
    }
}
```

When a `.POST` call is made to the server `InfoUtente` is posted and in this case i should **ignore** the `fidelity` property and allow `termini`

while when the user request the data with a `.GET` request i should return the whole object with `fidelity` but without `termini`.

I'm using the default serializator (JSON.NET), and i've tryed to use `JsonIgnore` on `termini` and in a `.GET` call it returns the right json without `termini` but if i try to make a `.POST` of `InfoUtente` with `JsonIgnore` on `termini` property, it will be ignored in .POST too and it's value will be set to false in any case..

So i should be able to `.POST` a JSON with

```
nome,cognome,cellulare,email,termini
```

and be able to `.GET` it with

```
nome,cognome,cellulare,email,fidelity
```

Should i make two different objects one with `termini` and without `fidelity` to use in `.POST` and another without `termini` and with `fidelity` to `.GET` or i could achieve it by using only one object?

Comment: Two objects is probably going to be simplest.

Comment: You should use two separate models, because this allows them to change independently and have their own individual requirements. From a security standpoint, this is also useful because by defining a model that represents just the data needed for a POST, you prevent your application being vulnerable to [over posting](https://andrewlock.net/preventing-mass-assignment-or-over-posting-in-asp-net-core/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating two different classes is indeed the best solution.

You might want to have a look into [Data Transfer Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) since they are also meant to achieve exactly what you want to do.

You would then have two classes, in addition to your InfoUtente entity. One for getting information about the particular instance you're interested in :

```
public class InfoUtenteDto
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public string cellulare { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fidelity { get; set; }
}
```

And another one, for creating a new instance :

```
public class InfoUtenteForCreationDto
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public string cellulare { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool termini { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ended up with the following approach.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is two interfaces with a custom Contract Resolver class. Assuming in addition to your class we have

```
public interface InfoUtentePost
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public string cellulare { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool termini { get; set; }
}

public interface InfoUtentGet
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public string cellulare { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string fidelity { get; set; }
}
```

Let's create a contract resolver

```
public class InterfaceContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly Type _InterfaceType;
    public InterfaceContractResolver(Type InterfaceType)
    {
        _InterfaceType = InterfaceType;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        //IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(_InterfaceType, memberSerialization);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

This is it, actually. The only thing we have to do now is to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` with some parameters:

```
InfoUtentePost product = new InfoUtente();

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new InterfaceContractResolver(typeof(InfoUtentePost))
};

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product, typeof(InfoUtentePost), settings);
 // output = "{\"nome\":null,\"cognome\":null,\"cellulare\":null,\"email\":null,\"termini\":false}"
```